# How to remove a specific character from a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like below.I would like to remove all \$ from the data.table. This character may exist in any column.

```
dt <- data.table("title"=c("First $Title", "Second Title", "Third Title", "Fourth Title"), 
             "sha"=c("12345", "234543; 33423", "22222567$8;", "6666623; New$444"),
             "date" = c("1/1/2020","1/2/2020","1/3/2020","1/4/2020$"))
```

I want to use data.table only

Comment: Use `dt[, lapply(.SD, gsub, pattern = "$", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)]`

Comment: thanks, what if I have a customer functions (cust_fun()) that the output is cleaned string. how to apply it on all columns?

Comment: Then, it is just `dt[, lapply(.SD, cust_fun)]`

Answer (score 2):

I think one thing you might consider is to take the approach that our colleague @akrun suggests, but do this in place, like this:

```
for(col in names(dt)) set(dt,j=col, value=gsub("$", "", dt[[col]], fixed=T))
```

Output:

```
          title             sha     date
         <char>          <char>   <char>
1:  First Title           12345 1/1/2020
2: Second Title   234543; 33423 1/2/2020
3:  Third Title      222225678; 1/3/2020
4: Fourth Title 6666623; New444 1/4/2020
```

This syntax also works:

```
cols = names(dt)
dt[, (cols):=lapply(.SD, gsub, pattern = "$", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)]
```